# OpenGL-ES mapping large vertex coordinates

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to build a 3D model of the earth using OpenGL-ES on Android.

now the measurements I use to construct the model is in Kilometers (1000 meters).

my question is: what is the best approach to construct the vertices:

A- using the Kilometers such as (1000,1500,0).

B- using the standard scale such as (1,1.5,0).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the approach A because you will be using floats. If you use the approach B the you will be stuck with Doubles which then will need to be converted to floats anyways.

That's what I use in my programs.